# use `sscanf` the same as `istringstream`?

Tags: c++, scanf, istringstream

Using `istringstream`, we could read items one by one from a string, for example:

```
istringstream iss("1 2 3 4");
int tmp;
while (iss >> tmp) {
    printf("%d \n", tmp);  // output: 1 2 3 4
}
```

could we do this using `sscanf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fairly closely simulate it with this

```
const char *s = "1 2 3 4";
int tmp, cnt;

for (const char *p = s; sscanf(p, "%d%n", &tmp, &cnt) == 1; p += cnt)
  printf("%d\n", tmp);
```

Comment: I am not sure if `%n` is counted by `sscanf`. I would make the test `>= 1` instead.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: It is not supposed to count it. The spec says: "Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the `fscanf` function."

Comment: [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) says that *"The C standard says:
              "Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment
              count returned at the completion of execution" but the
              Corrigendum seems to contradict this.  Probably it is wise not
              to make any assumptions on the effect of %n conversions on the
              return value. "*

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I don't know where they are getting this and what "corrigendum" they are referring to. C99 and later specs are very specific about this: `%n` does not count. Also, C99 made it clear that `*` (assignment suppression) cannot be used with `%n` (undefined beahvior), which is also contradicted by the text at your link. I think the text at the link is a not very well maintaned/reviewed conglomerate of multiple historical changes.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: "Not making any assumptions about the return value" is possible in this simplistic case, when only one field is read per call. But in more complex cases with multiple fields being read it is not possible to write proper code without knowing exactly how `%n` behaves.

Answer (score 2):

If you can break the string into separate tokens using [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

```
  char str[] ="1 2 3 4";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    int tmp;
    sscanf( pch, "%d", &tmp );
    printf( "%d \n", tmp );
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
```

Otherwise, scanf supports a %n conversion that would allow you to count the number of characters consumed so far (i haven't tested this, there may be pitfalls I haven't considered) ;

```
  char str[] ="1 2 3 4";
  int ofs = 0;
  while ( ofs < strlen(str) )
  {
    int tmp, ofs2;
    sscanf( &str[ofs], "%d %n", &tmp, &ofs2 );
    printf( "%d \n", tmp );
    ofs += ofs2;
  }
```